# Formatting an Excel sheet when copy/pasting from a website

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I'm trying to create a database from [this website](http://www.fifa.com/aboutfifa/organisation/footballgovernance/playeragents/list.html). Each country has loads of agents, with contact details next to their name (Fax Number and Company name are not required).

The problem is, due to the [format of the website](http://www.fifa.com/aboutfifa/organisation/footballgovernance/playeragents/association=alb.html), when I copy the data into my Excel sheet each Agent has information spread over 3 or 4 rows.

I need each Agent to have all their information on one row,

eg.(Cells in Brackets)

```
[ A1 ]       [ B1 ]             [ C1 ]  [ D1 ]                     [ E1 ]  [ F1 ]
GRO Alberti  alerti.ago@got.ch  Bosnia  P Hora K2 A 8 41 Dhjetori  Girana  Tel:+42-79/379 82 86.
```

I tried copy pasting it all manually, but this takes far too long.

Is there any automatic or quicker way of achieving what I'm trying to do?

Comment: I'd suggest you post this question on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/), as this is about programming. However, you should then try first and post a question showing what you tried and why it didn't work. Excel has a nice macro-recorder : you can play manually what you want to do, and look at the generated code.

Comment: Thanks d-stroyer, but I already tried there and my question got put on Hold because it was "off topic"

Comment: Right, I see [it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18333818/please-help-im-struggling-to-format-an-excel-sheet-for-work-non-programming-r) now. The point is that you would need to try first (an automated way) and then ask. You might consider my suggestion with the macro-recorder.

Comment: Also, you could consider breaking-up your problem : 1. Get the data from the web site to a (incompletely) formatted text/csv file ; 2. Use Excel, Python, or whatever to import the data into your excel file. Small questions are easier to answer than big ones.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly how you are getting the value of C1, but you should be able to get the source of the page. To do this, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>. This should give you a page written in html. Look for line 128 (or where the table starts, there should be the data you need there and it starts with `<table class ...`.

Copy everything from `<table class ...` to `</table>` which is on the same line, near to the end.

Paste this into notepad.

Click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> and use Find what: `<br />` Replace with: " " (one whitespace) and hit replace all.

Copy everything and paste in excel. You can remove the formatting after that to even out the cell dimensions.

Note that hyperlinks will stay in the data.

EDIT:

To separate the email, tel, mobile and fax will be a little longer, but not that long.

To get the email, use this formula in the next cell in E2:

```
=LEFT(D2, FIND(" ",D2)-1)
```

And drag down.

To get the numbers now, it'll be easier to get first all of them separately in column F:

```
=MID(D2, FIND(" ",D2)+1, LEN(D2))
```

Now in G, we'll get the Tel, in H we'll get the Fax and in I, we'll get the Mobile.

In G2, put and drag down:

```
=IFERROR(MID(F2,FIND("Tel:",F2)+4,IFERROR(FIND(":",F2,FIND("Tel:",F2)+4),LEN(F2))-FIND("Tel:",F2)-4),"")
```

In H2, put and drag down:

```
=IFERROR(MID(F2,FIND("Fax:",F2)+4,IFERROR(FIND(":",F2,FIND("Fax:",F2)+4),LEN(F2))-FIND("Fax:",F2)-4),"")
```

In I2, put and drag down:

```
=IFERROR(MID(F2,FIND("Mobile:",F2)+7,IFERROR(FIND(":",F2,FIND("Mobile:",F2)+7),LEN(F2))-FIND("Mobile:",F2)-7),"")
```

After that, copy everything and paste as values to remove formulas. Select columns G to I and replace all `Tel`, `Fax` and `Mobile` by nothing through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>.

### The french functions in order mentioned above:

```
=GAUCHE(D2, TROUVE(" ",D2)-1)

=STXT(D2, TROUVE(" ",D2)+1, NBCAR(D2))

=SIERREUR(STXT(F2,TROUVE("Tel:",F2)+4,SIERREUR(TROUVE(":",F2,TROUVE("Tel:",F2)+4),NBCAR(F2))-TROUVE("Tel:",F2)-4),"")

=SIERREUR(STXT(F2,TROUVE("Fax:",F2)+4,SIERREUR(TROUVE(":",F2,TROUVE("Fax:",F2)+4),NBCAR(F2))-TROUVE("Fax:",F2)-4),"")

=SIERREUR(STXT(F2,TROUVE("Mobile:",F2)+7,SIERREUR(TROUVE(":",F2,TROUVE("Mobile:",F2)+7),NBCAR(F2))-TROUVE("Mobile:",F2)-7),"")
```

Comment: Thanks, that has pretty much worked, except I need to separate the information in the "other info" column into 3 columns: Email, Landline, Mobile. Is there a way of doing this automatically by any chance? If not I just have to do it all manually.

Comment: @user2699532 I added some more stuff that you can use to do it quicker than manually :)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to do this, but i'm really sorry an error appears when i enter the first formula "=LEFT(D2, FIND(" ",D2)-1)"
It is: #NOM? (My Excel is In french so this is an error message in french.

Comment: @user2699532 Oh, just replace all the commas in all formulas with semicolons `;`. J'espere que cela resoud les erreurs :)

Comment: Im sorry but that didnt work either for me. I must be coming across as a complete Excel noob, but is there any other possible solution for those equations? 
If not, dont stress it Ill just do the whole thing manually.

Comment: @user2699532 I found the french versions of the formulas. Let me know if those work!

Comment: Not Everything works perfectly, but most of the stuff is good now.
Really appreciate it, thanks again.@jerry

Comment: @user2699532 You're welcome! To make things even faster though, a little script to extract and clean the data from the site would be better. If you know or want to learn a programming language, that could be a nice exercise :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Excel formulas:

- copy&paste the table into Excel

  - rows in first 2 columns will be merged, but formulas can see the value only in upper-left-most cell of the merged area, others cells appear blank for formulas
- assuming data start in cell `A2`, add following formula in cell `E2` - new line is entered by <kbd>Alt+Enter</kbd>:

  ```
  =C2 & IF($A3<>"", "", "
  " & E3)
  ```
- copy formula to appropriate range
- filter by `Name` column, excluding `(Blanks)`
- hide original `Address` and `Other info` columns
- copy & paste special as Values into a new sheet

[image: illustration of solution before last step]

The underlying algorithm is:

1. start at the bottom row
2. if `Name` in 1 row down is not empty, create a new string `S` containing Address from this row
   else add text from Address in this row to the beginning of `S`
3. move 1 row up